# Pagina em aspx rodando em asp net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, dll

Boa tarde, tenho uma  pagina em aspx que, através de alguns componentes, consegue gerar diversos documentos usados na empresa.
Pois bem, a pagina é em aspx e usa componentes (DLLs) proprietárias, nao podendo eu fazer engenharia reversa delas, e como o site está em migração total pra MVC agora, gostaria de que, pelo menos essa, rodasse em aspx mesmo.
Tem como fazer algo assim?

Comment: Favoritei. Vou escrever um guia pra você.

Comment: Sua resposta muito me interessa @Cigano

Answer (score 3):

> Esta resposta deverá sofrer uma série de alterações nos próximos dias, de acordo com as dúvidas subsequentes do autor da pergunta a aspectos específicos da sua aplicação. Pode ser que outras questões possam ser abertas ou usadas para explicitar algum aspecto mais complexo. Estarei lendo os comentários todos os dias. Favor me mencionar nos comentários para que eu possa melhorar a resposta direcionando para a sua dúvida.

Vou esmiuçar alguns aspectos na resposta. Se necessário, irei acrescentando mais no passar dos dias. A ideia é usar essas ideias como um roteiro para a sua migração.

## 1. Ao converter seu projeto, você não precisa usar suas Views em Razor

Antes de mais nada, é importante dizer que migrar uma aplicação ASP.NET para ASP.NET MVC não necessariamente quer dizer que o motor Razor será usado para gerar as *Views*. O MVC suporta geração de *Views* através de páginas legadas. Isto pode ser facilmente visto ao criar um novo projeto ASP.NET MVC4:

[image: ASP.NET MVC Usando ASPX]

## 2. Views em MVC não possuem *Code Behind*, e nem devem possuir

Este passo é inevitável: será necessário transferir toda e qualquer lógica do seu *Code Behind* para dois possíveis lugares:

- Controller
- Eventos JavaScript

## 3. Postback não existe em MVC

Basicamente um Postback é uma abstração de 3 partes:

- Alguma lógica JavaScript;
- Algum código HTML;
- Algum comportamento do lado do servidor (Server-Side).

Na época em que o AJAX Toolkit foi projetado, toda essa lógica era muito trabalhosa de ser feita. Hoje em dia temos uma miríade de bibliotecas JavaScript que simplificam o trabalho e permitem ao programador estender o comportamento do JavaScript além do possível no AJAX Toolkit, o que o tornou prolixo e complexo de manter.

A substituição clássica do Postback pode ser feita utilizando, por exemplo:

- JQuery;
- Razor ou ASPX;
- Eventos no Controller que devolvam:

  - JSON;
  - Partial Views;

## 4. Seus Controllers devem chamar as DLLs proprietárias

Referencie suas DLLs normalmente dentro do projeto MVC, assim como é feito no projeto ASP.NET Clássico. As chamadas a cada classe e método são feitas da mesma forma.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou estudá-la e se tiver alguma duvida postarei aqui, novamente obrigado!